# Bug ao usar Select2 em um form-group do Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

Estou com uma dificuldade em corrigir um bug que acontece ao utilizar o **Select2** em um `input-group`. O problema é que ao selecionar um `option` com nome muito extenso, o `input-group` não respeita a largura do elemento pai.

```
<div class='elemento_pai' style='width:200px;'>
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="select2">
        <option></option>
        <option>Nome extenso Nome extenso Nome extenso Nome extenso Nome extenso</option>
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="submit">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que acontece é que o `input-group` acaba ficando com um `width` maior do que `200px`, não respeitando o `elemento_pai`. Alguém que já passou por isso achou uma solução?

[Exemplo do problema no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmRv4/1/)

Issues sem solução:

- https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/2472
- https://github.com/t0m/select2-bootstrap-css/issues/42

Comment: Acho que falta o elemento-pai no seu exemplo do Fiddle.

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição no exemplo do JSFiddle não precisa do elemento_pai, basta diminuir o tamanho da janela do seu navegador e você irá perceber que o select não vai respeitar a largura. Esse `elemento_pai` foi apenas para ilustrar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução:

```
.select2-container .select2-choice > .select2-chosen{
  white-space: normal;
}
```

[Exemplo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmRv4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a melhor resposta mas pelo o que eu encontrei pra solucionar seu caso, você deve colocar o primeiro `<option>` com o texto pequeno

Exemplo:

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>

      <select id="lunch" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" title="Please select a lunch ...">
        <option value="1">Nome extenso Nome extenso Nome extenso Nome extenso Nome extenso Nome extenso Nome extensoNome extenso Nome extenso</option>
        <option selected>Select 1</option>
        <option>Select 2</option>
        <option>Select 2</option>
        <option>Select 2</option>
        <option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div>
```

Achei a resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054119/input-group-addon-with-bootstrap-select).

Comment: Antony, a questão está relacionado ao uso do Select2 com `input-group`, essa sua resposta não resolve o meu problema, mas obrigado pela intenção.